# delphi TCollection count not increasing after Add

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcollection, townedcollection

i have the types

- TNotifyReply = class(TCollectionItem)
- TNotifyReplylist = class(TOwnedCollection)

NotifyReplylist := TNotifyReplylist.Create(self, TNotifyReply);

After calling this function (Any number of times), Count it still zero

```
function TNotifyReplylist.addItem: TNotifyReply;
 begin
   Result := inherited Add as TNotifyReply;
   OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar('Count > '+ inttostr(count)));
 end;
```

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: Your code is working as expected for me. Only had to change PAnsiChar to PChar as I am using D2009. Don't think TCollection(Item) has changed much since D7 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem, TNotifyReply.Create was

```
constructor TNotifyReply.Create(ACollection: TCollection);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  ....
```

changed to

```
inherited Create(ACollection);
```

Comment: That's actually a very common mistake that people make. :-) My advise? Rename the Collection variable in your class to FCollection. (Unless it's a property but then again, do you want programmers to have direct access to the collection?)

Comment: @Workshop, `Collection` is a property of the base `TCollectionItem` class. You *do* want developers to have direct access to that, or else items won't know who the belong to. The property gets assigned by using the value from the constructor argument.